# Problem with sending HDLC frames by using GSM modem

Tags: gsm, frames, modem, dlms

I have SL7000 meter and GSM Modem iRZ. When i send by using RS-485 cable - everything work. But when i'm trying to use GSM modem i'm getting issues.
When i send SNRM like this:
7E A0 0A 00 22 00 51 03 93 6A 34 7E
I get normal UA.
But when i try to send SNRM like this:
7E A0 21 00 22 00 51 03 93 6B 21 81 80 12 05 01 80 07 04 00 00 00 02 08 04 00 00 00 01 3D 93 7E (It's from DXDLMSDirector)
I get nothing. Absolutely!
Maybe there is some trick to use hdlc with gsm modem? Maybe special delays or something?

Answer (score 0):

If both of these frames work via the RS-485, and not via the GSM, then there are a couple of possible answers:
1) the addressing you are using is not permitted if this is a seperate port
2) if it is the same port on the meter, then the GSM Modem is not directing traffic to the same RS485 address